# Variable can be echoed but PHP returns undefined error when trying to use it with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to save a variable's value into a db using PDO, however I am getting  `Undefined variable` error.

The odd thing is that I can successfully echo the variable in the same block of code but still the error indicates that the variable is not defined on the next line (after the echo statement)!

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT po_number FROM po ORDER BY po_number DESC LIMIT 1 ;";
    $STH = $pdo ->query($sql);
    $row = $STH->fetch();
    $myVar = $row['po_number'];
?>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['addProduct'])){
        echo $myVar;  //the variable can be echoed with the expected value here

        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO po_parts (po_number, part_id, quantity) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $statement1->bindParam(1, $myVar);
        //I am getting error that $myVar is undefined on the previous line

        $statement1->bindParam(2, $_POST['part']);
        $statement1->bindParam(3, $_POST['quantity']);
        if($statement1->execute()){
            $message = "Product was added successfully to the order number $newVar";
        }else{
            $message = "OP's was NOT added successfully.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Could anyone tell me what is the problem here?

Thank you.

Comment: You dont set `$statement1` anywhere

Comment: You are correct, my bad.. thank you very much I missed that.

Comment: Also from the file alone not even $pdo is set.You need `$pdo=new PDO(blah blah`

Comment: that was already done in different part in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prepare your statement before you can use it.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT po_number FROM po ORDER BY po_number DESC LIMIT 1 ;";
    $STH = $pdo ->query($sql);
    $row = $STH->fetch();
    $myVar = $row['po_number'];
?>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['addProduct'])){
        echo $myVar;  //the variable can be echoed with the expected value here

        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO po_parts (po_number, part_id, quantity) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        // Inserted this row
        $statement1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1);

        $statement1->bindParam(1, $myVar);
        //I am getting error that $myVar is undefined on the previous line

        $statement1->bindParam(2, $_POST['part']);
        $statement1->bindParam(3, $_POST['quantity']);
        if($statement1->execute()){
            $message = "Product was added successfully to the order number $newVar";
        }else{
            $message = "OP's was NOT added successfully.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to prepare the statement before inserting:

```
$statement1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
```

More information on MySQLi PDO syntax at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp.